# In finding $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_y$ for $f(x,y,z)=c$, why does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_y=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the formula for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_y$ given $f(x,y,z)=c$ for $c$ constant, and writing $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and using the chain rule I can get to
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_y = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{yz} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|_{xy} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_y .$$

In order to get the formula I need to set the LHS of the equation to zero, but I'm unsure why this is the case.

Please can somebody explain what $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_y$ represents for $f$, and why it is $0$ in this case?

Edit: Where $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_y$ means the derivative with y held constant.

Comment: It seems to be that the actual, precise definition of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_y$ is "the partial derivative of $\;\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\;$ with respect to $\;y\;$ , but...is this really so?

Comment: @DonAntonio I've edited the question to explain my notation - the vertical bar represents the variables held constant.

Comment: @acemine I just can't wrap my mind about that weird concept...if a function is constant, as your is, all the partial derivatives of all orders are zero, whether some variable is kept constant or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the relation $f(x,y,z)=c$ as defining $z$ as a function of the **independent** variables $x,y$. Therefore, when you take the derivative with respect to $x$, 
$$
\partial f/\partial x+\partial f/\partial y\cdot\partial y/\partial x+\partial f/\partial z\cdot\partial z/\partial x=0
$$
you set $\partial y/\partial x=0$.

It is actually better to use differentials:
$$
\partial f/\partial x\cdot dx+\partial f/\partial y\cdot dy+\partial f/\partial z\cdot dz=0
$$
and since you are considering the variation with respect to $x$, you set $dy=0$ and compute $\partial z/\partial x$.

Comment: How do you get the equality with 0 in $
\partial f/\partial x+\partial f/\partial y\cdot\partial y/\partial x+\partial f/\partial z\cdot\partial z/\partial x=0
$? I thought it might be by differentiating $f(x,y,z)=c$, but then wouldn't you also get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{yz}=0$, which is not true in general?

Comment: The first term is precisely $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ for fixed $y,z$. You differentiate the identity $f(x,y,z(x,y))=c$ with respect to $x$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: I think I understand now - to make sure I'm right, when you differentiate wrt x, are you holding just $y$ constant? So taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_y$ of both sides?

Comment: That is exactly right.